# php parser: Determine if string found via regex is inside an anchor tag

Tags: php, regex, parsing, dom, anchor

**Edited.** I know HTML should not be parsed with regex. *I am asking for help.* How can I find an arbitrary string in a mix of tags and text and then determine if it is inside an anchor?

I have an interactive glossary in my WordPress site. Part of **its functionality is searching the content of a post for a glossary term (a text string). If found, the term is wrapped in a link to a custom taxonomy entry that contains the definition.**

I like how it works, but one hitch is that if the term is already part of a link, the glossary parser hijacks the current link, by inserting a link within the link. The parser is purely regex based, there isn't DOM parsing. **I know that HTML should not be parsed with regex**. But currently the function is just searching for a specific text string, its not trying to do anything with tags at all.

**But is there a relatively fast (in terms of processing) and reliable way I can check if the found string is inside an anchor tag?** Obviously this would not always be the case, as the word could be seemingly be inside any tag. The glossary parser would not add a link in this case. I know this feature would use a DOM parser, but I'm unsure where to go from here.

The parser:

```
function glossary_parse($content){

    //Run the glossary parser
    if (((!is_page() && get_option('glossaryOnlySingle') == 0) OR
    (!is_page() && get_option('glossaryOnlySingle') == 1 && is_single()) OR
    (is_page() && get_option('glossaryOnPages') == 1))){
        $glossary_index = get_children(array(
                                            'post_type'     => 'glossary',
                                            'post_status'   => 'publish',
                                            ));
        $current_title = get_the_title();                                   
        if ($glossary_index){
            $timestamp = time();
            foreach($glossary_index as $glossary_item){
                $timestamp++;
                $glossary_title = $glossary_item->post_title;
                if ($current_title == $glossary_title) {
                continue;
                }
                $glossary_search = '/\b'.$glossary_title.'s*?\b(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/i';
                $glossary_replace = '<a'.$timestamp.'>$0</a'.$timestamp.'>';
                if (get_option('glossaryFirstOnly') == 1) {
                    $content_temp = preg_replace($glossary_search, $glossary_replace, $content, 1);
                }
                else {
                    $content_temp = preg_replace($glossary_search, $glossary_replace, $content);
                }
                $content_temp = rtrim($content_temp);

                    $link_search = '/<a'.$timestamp.'>('.$glossary_item->post_title.'[A-Za-z]*?)<\/a'.$timestamp.'>/i';
                    if (get_option('glossaryTooltip') == 1) {
                        $link_replace = '<a class="glossaryLink" href="' . get_permalink($glossary_item) . '" title="Glossary: '. $glossary_title . '" onmouseover="tooltip.show(\'' . addslashes($glossary_item->post_excerpt) . '\');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">$1</a>';
                    }
                    else {
                        $link_replace = '<a class="glossaryLink" href="' . get_permalink($glossary_item) . '" title="Glossary: '. $glossary_title . '">$1</a>';
                    }
                    $content_temp = preg_replace($link_search, $link_replace, $content_temp);
                    $content = $content_temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning to not use a parser?

Comment: I agree with alex, this is a mess.

Comment: The canonical answer as to why what you want is going to be ugly/painful/pointless: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML with regex, it's like trying to chisel a dove-tail joint with a hacksaw.  While there's nothing wrong with hacksaws, they're the wrong tool to make dove-tail joints with, and regex is the wrong tool to parse HTML with.  Use PHP's DOM parser instead.

Comment: @GordonM: how can PHP's DOM parser help me find arbitrary text strings? I mean, I'm still gonna have to use regex right? If you read the question, I'm looking to add DOM parsing, and am not even attempting to do any currently, just looking for a text string. Please don't answer questions all knee-jerk with pedantic woodworking metaphors.

Comment: @alex I'm not parsing any HTML at this point. Just flat out looking for strings - it didn't matter where in the HTML they were when I wrote this. There was no point. Now I've found a use case where there is a point, and I'm asking for help on how to do some parsing.